# Увеличивать textarea при необходимости

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Как увеличивать `textarea`, когда текста становится больше, чем можно увидеть в блоке? Это можно сделать на css? Если знаете решение на js, напишите, не принципиально на css
Мне также подойдёт абсолютно любая конструкция, куда можно вводить текст и блок будет увеличиваться

```css
textarea {
  resize: none;
  min-height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="add__text" placeholder="Описание"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Увы, такое нельзя провернуть на CSS.

Как вариант использовать блок, которые будет повторять размеры, отступы, стиль текста и т.п. и содержать в себе тот же текст, а потом, за счёт изменения его размера, увеличивать и размер textarea.

Не очень, но пример: (Используется jQuery)

```js
let ghost = $('#ghost');

$('textarea').on('keypress change', function(){
  let text = $(this).val();
  ghost.text(text);
  
  let ghostHeight = ghost.height();
  $(this).height(ghostHeight);
  
  console.clear();
  console.info(`Высота textarea == ${Math.ceil(ghostHeight*100)/100}px`);
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.45;
}

textarea, #ghost {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: inherit;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-break: break-word;
}

textarea {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  color: #333;
  resize: none;
  transition: height .05s linear;
}

#ghost {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea placeholder="Введите текст"></textarea>
<div id="ghost"></div>
```

---

**UPD**

Нашёл подобный вопрос с готовым решением, тут можно сказать уже совсем готовый вариант.

Ссылка на ответ - [Клик](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346855/7692602)

Answer (score 2):

Я использовал такой способ, [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize/5346855#5346855):
Действия ресайза заключил в `requestAnimationFrame` и задал `transition` для `height`, для того, чтобы избежать дрыганья блока

```js
let observe;
let text = document.querySelector('.add__text');

if (window.attachEvent) {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
} else {
    observe = function (element, event, handler) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}

function init() {
    function resize () {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }

    function delayedResize() {
        requestAnimationFrame(function() {
            resize();
        });

    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}

init();
```

```css
textarea {
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .2s linear;
  resize: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="add__text" placeholder="Описание"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще есть один интересный вариант:

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.autoResize = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
      onResize: function() {},
      animate: true,
      animateDuration: 150,
      animateCallback: function() {},
      extraSpace: 20,
      limit: 1000
    }, options);
    this.filter('textarea').each(function() {
      var textarea = $(this).css({
          resize: 'none',
          'overflow-y': 'hidden'
        }),
        origHeight = textarea.height(),
        clone = (function() {
          var props = ['height', 'width', 'lineHeight', 'textDecoration', 'letterSpacing'],
            propOb = {};
          $.each(props, function(i, prop) {
            propOb[prop] = textarea.css(prop);
          });
          return textarea.clone().removeAttr('id').removeAttr('name').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: -9999
          }).css(propOb).attr('tabIndex', '-1').insertBefore(textarea);
        })(),
        lastScrollTop = null,
        updateSize = function() {
          clone.height(0).val($(this).val()).scrollTop(10000);
          var scrollTop = Math.max(clone.scrollTop(), origHeight) + settings.extraSpace,
            toChange = $(this).add(clone);
          if (lastScrollTop === scrollTop) {
            return;
          }
          lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
          if (scrollTop >= settings.limit) {
            $(this).css('overflow-y', '');
            return;
          }
          settings.onResize.call(this);
          settings.animate && textarea.css('display') === 'block' ?
            toChange.stop().animate({
              height: scrollTop
            }, settings.animateDuration, settings.animateCallback) :
            toChange.height(scrollTop);
        };
      textarea
        .unbind('.dynSiz')
        .bind('keyup.dynSiz', updateSize)
        .bind('keydown.dynSiz', updateSize)
        .bind('change.dynSiz', updateSize);
    });
    return this;
  };
  $(function() {
    $('textarea').autoResize({
      extraSpace: 0
    });
  })
})(jQuery);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 0.938em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #111;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  outline: none;
}

.form_input textarea {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 50px;
  max-height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form_input textarea:hover,
.form_input textarea:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 0 5px 1px #f1f1f1;
}

.form_input>textarea~.f_focus {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #006faf;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.form_input>textarea~.f_focus {
  bottom: 0;
}

.form_input>textarea:focus~.f_input {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form_input"><textarea class="f_input" placeholder="Описание"></textarea></div>
```

Comment: У вас есть это дребезжание, как раз